# Rails CSV Import Duplicating Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, heroku, import

I've managed to get CSV imports working (based on [this repo](https://github.com/RichIsOnRails/CSVImportExample)) on a Rails 4 app. The issue is that on my development system, the imports appear to work correctly, but in production, all records get duplicated. See existing code below. Any ideas what could be causing the duplication? All records appear in the CSV once only, all have blank ID columns since I want the system to assign the assigns.

books_controller.rb

```
def import
    begin
      Book.import(params[:file])
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Books imported."
    rescue
     redirect_to root_url, notice: "Invalid CSV file format."
    end
end

def create
  @book = Book.new(book_params)
  @book.save
  save_previews(params[:previews])
  respond_with(@book)
end

def save_previews images
  if images
    images.each_value { |image|
    @book.previews.create(image: image)
    }
  end
end
```

book.rb

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, :encoding => 'utf-8') do |row|

    product_hash = row.to_hash
    product = Book.where(id: product_hash["id"])

    if product.count == 1
      product.first.update_attributes(product_hash)
    else
      Book.create!(product_hash)
    end # end if !product.nil?
  end # end CSV.foreach
end # end self.import(file)
```

routes.rb

```
resources :books do
    get "books/:page", :action => :index, :on => :collection
    resources :comments
    collection do 
      post :import
    end
end
```

users#show.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.super_admin? %>
  <%= form_tag import_books_path, multipart: true do %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= file_field_tag :file %>
      <%= submit_tag "Import CSV", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: In your code it is helpful to keep the class definitions and whatnot. For example, I wanted to make sure you were using active record.

Comment: i am using active record yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [active record validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) to make sure that you get no duplicates. This would be the `uniqueness` validation to make sure that there is only one record with that attribute. You will want a scope on that attribute to tie all of the other attributes together.

Here is a simple example:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :title, scope: :product_id
end
```

Comment: the titles are not necessarily unique. there can be multiple products with the same information (same title, date, writer, artist, etc), and the only difference would be the note and image fields. Currently, if I'm adding single records via the admin interface, I can upload an image via (image field) with paperclip, or via a link (image_remote_url) which then processes with paperclip in the background. Maybe i can do:

    class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates_uniqueness_of :image_remote_url, scope: :product_id
    end

Since this is the only way to upload images via CSV.

Comment: Dbz, great suggestion. I made image_remote_url the unique field and it works like a charge.